# Can the 3 items that Rabban Gamliel requires during the Seder be explained using sign language?

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada, translation, deaf

Pesach Haggadah, Magid, Rabban Gamliel's Three Things:

> רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל הָיָה אוֹמֵר: כָּל שֶׁלֹּא **אָמַר** שְׁלשָׁה
> דְּבָרִים אֵלּוּ בַּפֶּסַח, לא יָצָא יְדֵי חוֹבָתוֹ, וְאֵלּוּ הֵן
>
> פֶּסַח, מַצָּה, וּמָרוֹר.
>
> Rabban Gamliel was accustomed to say, Anyone who has not **said**
> these three things on Pesach has not fulfilled his obligation, and
> these are them:
>
> the Pesach sacrifice, matsa and *marror*.

I have bolded the word *said* (in both Hebrew and English). Must these 3 items be said orally, or can a person use sign language to "say" these things, and still fulfill the requirement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means who didn't explain it, why we eat all those things, so saying just the words wouldn't be sufficient either, so sign language is just fine.

שולחן ערוך אורח חיים תעג סעיף ו
הגה: ויאמר בלשון שמבינים הנשים והקטנים או יפרש להם הענין וכן עשה ר"י מלונדרי כל ההגדה בלשון לע"ז כדי שיבינו הנשים והקטנים

Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim 473:6

Note: And he should say Hagadah in language which women and children understand or he should explain it to them what is it all about, and so did Rav Y. from Londri, the whole Hagadah he said in his native language in order that women and kids should understand.

Comment: I had a sense that the term *Amar* means "explain" - you (actually, R. Kairo) explained it. I have not heard of a place called "Londri". Is it clean? ;-)

Comment: I don't know where is at all, just people complain when it's not translated, so, here you have it :P